# Round() function is not showing up in my GUI

Tags: python

When I run my script:

```
def rate(self, activeCount):
    activeRate = (activeCount/64)/1.5
   #function of activeRate here
    round(activeRate, 3)
    self.incRate.setText(f' {activeRate}/min')
```

I can't seem to get this rounding feature to show up in my GUI, however I know the function works when printed. Does anyone know why this is not visuallizing to my GUI in pyqt5? The QLabel is named incRate.

Comment: You're not doing anything with your rounded value

Comment: This has nothing to do with PyQt, or UI in general.

Comment: the #function here, should have clarified that yes, indeed it was being used.

Comment: @pippettejockey the fact that it didn't display, clarifies that it was only *used*, not that the result was *assigned*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`round` is not an "in-place" conversion.

Use `activeRate = round(activeRate, 3)`, or directly use the format syntax, which uses the same implementation as `round`:

```py
self.incRate.setText(f' {activeRate:.3f}/min')
```

Comment: Finally, yeah this worked. Not sure why I didn't try that, thanks for the help!